# Install libcurl for C++ in Windows

Tags: c++, gcc, libcurl

this is my first time trying to install a library, and I have next-to-no idea as to how I'd do that. I'm using GCC in codeblocks. Do I download the MinGW64 binary or development build? From there where do/should I extract it to. After that, I believe I have to link it to GCC, how do I accomplish that? Is there anything else after that? I found results on Google, but all they did for me was confuse me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Downloading MinGW binaries for windows should be sufficient. Dev build from source is only necessary if you want to contribute to the GCC toolchain itself, or change build parameters for it (which is unlikely for the context you're asking for).

When you have installed your MinGW GCC toolchain properly, you should be able to download `libcurl` as source distribution and compile it with this toolchain.

Comment: So how do I go  about linking libcurl? It doesn't seem like I can use the libcurl.dll

Comment: Elaborate on your particular errors then (in a separate SO question may be!!).